# Replace UrlEncodedFormEntity with stringEntity Android

Tags: android

I want to ask you a question about `setHeader` in android , I am trying to modify `setEntity` :

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "utf-8"));
```

to :

```
StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity("name=value1&price=value2$=&description=value3", "UTF-8");

httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);
```

In my sever , `_POST` can't receive information util I add header to `httpPost` :

```
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
```

I do the same with `HttpURLConnection` , just change `"name=value1&price=value2&description=value3"` to bytes then write in `outputStream` and `_POST` can receive information . Why do I have to `setHeader` to `httpPost`?